# In e2e testing, blank page is opened in Chromium Edge (New Edge Browser) using Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

1.Open the MS Chromium edge and type the command "`edge://settings/help`" to check the version
2. Download the [MS Chromium edge webdriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) and placed it into project directory
3. Set the desired capabilities in conf.js file 
4. Start the server using command `"webdriver-manager start --edge msedgedriver.exe"`
5. Run the test using the "`protractor conf.js`"

Environment:

```
Chromium Edge Version =  83.0.478.37
Chromium web driver   = 83.0.478.37
Selenium server version = 3.141.59
JDK  =1.8.191
```

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
     capabilities: {
       'browserName': 'chrome',
       'goog:chromeOptions': {
        // Faked out chrome binary
        'binary':'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedge.exe'
      }

    },
    //Path of Chromium edge driver
    chromeDriver:'./msedgedriver.exe',

    specs: ['spec.js'],
    }
  };
```

Also tried with using desired capabilities in spec.js file as well but still blank page is opened

```
describe('slow calculator', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        let options = new edge.Options();
        options.setEdgeChromium(true);
        //options.setBinaryPath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Beta\\Application\\msedge.exe");

        let browser = edge.Driver.createSession(options);

        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

    });
 });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While starting webdriver-manager, ensure the path to msedgedriver is specified.

```
webdriver-manager start --edge "pathToEdgeDriver/msedgedriver.exe"
```

The capabilities object should have MicrosoftEdge as browserName.

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge'
    }
```